# How to perform click() to a webElement if certain condition is met (Selenium, JS)

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver

I'm using Selenium and JavaScript.

I already could obtain a list of webelements that correspond to certain condition, but after that I want to make another condition and if that condition is met to click the element.

I have the following:

```
this.driver.findElement(By.css(".container")).then( function(trueFalse) {
        if (trueFalse) {
            // If the container is visible, it returns all the posible checkboxes
            return driver.findElements(By.css(".container li[role='checkbox']"));
        } else {
            console.log("Err. Container NOT visible");
        }
    }).then(function(eleArray) {
        // Iterates through all the posible filters and clicks the ones that match the desired filters
        for(var i = 0; i < eleArray.length; i++) {

            eleArray[i].getAttribute('innerHTML')
                .then(function(text) {
                    if (desiredFilters.includes(text)) {
                        // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
                        return click();
                    }
                });       
        }
    });
```

If instead of returning **click()** (which I know is wrong) I return **text**, it works correctly, I am being able to discriminate the desired filters from the overall posible filters, but i dont know how to perform the click when all of the conditions are met.

Comment: just craft an XPATH that does the work for you.  No need for all this if/then logic. You'll get the webelement or an exception.

Comment: It could work, but I am trying to do it programatically , so that I can select as many as I want only changing the array *desiredFilters*

Comment: the XPATH would be a string, so construct it using the strings in the array. That'll tell you if they exist or not... you'll either get the webelement or an exception.  You can use .click method of the webelement.  The "contains" method of xpath may be useful here.

Comment: why you want to retun ? a.click , return null or somethign or no return at all ?

Comment: I do not need, for saying, to return a click(), with the code above I know if the element is what I'm searching for but do not know how to click it now that I have found it.